# how to display a div for an empty textarea?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to raise a DIV, when someone click the 'Submit' button leaving the textarea empty.

Here is my form:

http://pastebin.com/1K3Ci9QA

Please, help me.

Comment: why is this java?
plus i didn't understod the problem

Comment: So you want to empty the textarea when the form is submitted? BTW, is that tag `java` or `javascript`?

Comment: Sorry for my unwanted mistake. But, you don't have to downvote for that. Mistakes are normal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hope I understand you right.You need to validate, that form field is NOT empty.
You can use such function:

```
<script>
function validateForm() {
    var x = document.forms["AddNameOfYourForm"]["login"].value;
    if (x==null || x=="") {
        alert("Login area must be filled out");
        return false;
    }
}
</script>
```

You can check different variants here:
http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_form_validation.asp

And I hope you ask about javascript function :)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll try & let you know. Thanks everyone for answers. :D

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<script language='javascript'>
function validate()
{
if(document.getElementById('login').length == 0)
{
  document.getElementById('message').style.display = 'block';
  return false;
}
else
{
  document.forms[0].submit();
}
}
</script>

<div id='message' style='display:none;'>Please fill in the form</div>
<form method='post' action='registration_site'>
<textarea id='login' name='login'></textarea>
<input type='button' name='logsubmit' value='Submit' onClick='validate();'/>
</form>
```

Comment: can you give me this in jsfiddle or pastebin?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/6JnWgwXi

Comment: I don't know why, but this is not working!

Can you please see what is wrong?

http://crownglass.ga/site_4.xhtml

Answer (score 0):

I dont think it's will work.
because when it is a form and you use method post 
it will take you to the action

BTW Ray's answer on pastebin

```
http://pastebin.com/ymAQNTQp
```